# ExtAudioFileRead do sometimes throw exception upon read

Tags: ios, core-audio

Hi,
I'm having a really hard time with some "random" crashes from an app Im currently working on.

I use ExtAudioFileRead to read data from an CFURLRef (an audiofile of the m4a format) into a PCM buffer for interpretation. However, sometimes one of the ExtAudioFileRead-calls throws an: 
CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList and I just cannot understand why. I've looked around and cannot find anything that helps.

It has never appeared in the simulator only upon deployed hardware (iPhone4s with iOS 5.0 and 5.1, aswell as iPad2 running iOS 5.1)

I will of course paste source code to make the question clearer but it will take some time until I've polished it enough for your judging eyes.

So, in the meantime: any thoughts? Have you experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is because of AVAudioSession. This problem may occur when you record audio and then save audio and play again that audio. You might have created AVAudioSession instance while playing audio. so,

1) Remove audio from temp directory when you have saved audio.

2) Do not create AVAudioSessio instance, if it is not necessary.